# Android change database path issue

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

I have a little problem with changing the path of my database in my custom `databaseHelper.class`. So in the beginning I put the database in default database folder in Internal Storage, but now I want to place it in `files/documents/users/servername/data`, but when I change the string which initialize my storage path the database which is placed there is empty. I forgot to mention that actually I have the sqlite file in my application's asset folder and I'm copying the file from there to my internal memory. So here is a piece of the code which I'm using :

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH_PREFIX = "/data/data/";
private static String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";

public UserDatabaseHelper(Context context,  // String dbname,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context,"stampii_tpl.sqlite", factory, version);
        this.context = context;
        Log.i(TAG, "Create or Open database : " + "stampii_tpl.sqlite");
}

private static void copyDataBase(Context aContext)
                throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = aContext.getAssets().open("stampii_tpl.sqlite");

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath(aContext);

        Log.i(TAG, "Check if create dir : " + DB_PATH_PREFIX
                        + aContext.getPackageName() + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);

        // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
        File f = new File(DB_PATH_PREFIX + aContext.getPackageName()
                        + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdir();

        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to copy local DB to : " + outFileName);

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "DB (" + "stampii_tpl.sqlite" + ") copied!");
}
private static boolean checkDatabase(Context aContext) {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
                String myPath = getDatabasePath(aContext);

                Log.i(TAG, "Trying to conntect to : " + myPath);
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                Log.i(TAG, "Database " + "stampii_tpl.sqlite" + " found!");
                checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Database " + "stampii_tpl.sqlite" + " does not exists!");

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static String getDatabasePath() {
        return getDatabasePath(context);
}

private static String getDatabasePath(Context aContext) {
        return DB_PATH_PREFIX + aContext.getPackageName() + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
                        + "stampii_tpl.sqlite";
}
```

And if I try to change the `DB_PATH_SUFFIX` to : `/files/documents/users/servername/data` the database which I have there is empty and don't have the tables which are created in the file from assets folder.

So any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether `files/documents/users/servername/data` is relative your application or the root file system.

Rule of thumb: Don't use absolute path names pointing out to/from the root filesystem. Ever. Things *will* break and end up in silly bugs!

To get the root dir of your application, use this:

```
String ROOT_DIR = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

From there, move your database to wherever you want (beneath your app's storage tree).

Comment: Actually the path to my database folder now is `data/data/app_package_name/databases`  and I want to copy the file to `data/data/app_package_name/files/documents/users/data` but actually with your code it's even not creating the directories and copying an empty file to `databases` directory. Any ideas where can be my mistake?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29 is probably useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `getDatabasePath()` method in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public File getDatabasePath(String name)
{
    //blah-blah
}
```